# Count cells of a DataGridView with the same value and display the result

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview, count

I have a DataGridview with 9 Columns and the last Column says "Finished".
This Column's values are: `Completed`, `In-Repair`, `Build In Progress`, `Not Started`.
I want to count how many `Completed` cells there are and display the result in a Label, such as: "23 Rows Show Completed".

I have tried everything I know but cannot get it to work.
I've tried using `System.Linq` and `for each` but I just can't get it to work.

```
int xCount = dataGridView1.Rows
                  .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                  .Select(row => row.Cells["Finished"].Value.ToString())
                  .Count(s => s == "Completed");
                lbl3.Text = xCount.ToString();
```

Comment: You might have null values or your DGV has a `new Row` (all null values). Add a null check: `int xCount = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Count(r => r.Cells["Finished"].Value != null && r.Cells["Finished"].Value.ToString().Equals("Completed"));`. This, of course, if your `Column[8].Name = "Finished"`, not the header text.

Comment: _but I just can't get it to work_ - can you elaborate more? Did you get an error or some other not expected behaviour?

Comment: That worked THANK YOU, i didn't even realize my dgv was having a automatic add row i thought i disabled it

Answer (score 0):

Try using index

```
int xCount = dataGridView1.Rows
              .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
              .Select(row => row.Cells[8].Value.ToString() == "Completed").Count();
            lbl3.Text = xCount.ToString();
```

Comment: Object Reference Not set to a instance of an object

Comment: or i get Index out of range if i put it under cellformatting

Comment: how much columns do you have?

Comment: and how much "Completed" rows did you have when your ran your code?

Comment: Jimi Has the answer i didnt check for null values my mistake.