# count DataGridView cells with equal values

Tags: c#, count, datagridview, numbers, label

I have a DataGridView that receives a list of lottery numbers, I would like to count how many times the same number appeared in the grid list, I have an image for example, I am using this code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFlQb.png)

```
private void calculaTotalGrid()
    {
        ResultadoNumeros numer = new ResultadoNumeros();
        int badCount = dgLista.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "01").Count();
        lbl_01.Text = badCount.ToString();
    } 

          int val;
        int valToCount = 10;
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var row in dgLista.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
            foreach (var cell in row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>())
                count += int.TryParse(cell.Value?.ToString(),
                    out  val) && val == valToCount ? 1 : 0;
                       txtNum.Text = count.ToString();
```

Could someone help me or give me a light on how to do this?
minha class ResultadoNumeros

```
public int concurso { get; set; }
    public int _01 { get; set; }
    ----
    public int _15 { get; set; }
```

class

```
public static DataTable ObterNumeros()
    {
        DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
        DALConexao conexao = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDaConexao);
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
          cmd.Connection = conexao.ObjetConexao;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from TBLotofacil ORDER BY Concurso DESC", conexao.StringConexao);
             da.Fill(tabela);
        return tabela;
    }        
}
```

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093479/count-cells-of-a-datagridview-with-the-same-value-and-display-the-result

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this is the code I'm using and the result is 0, this code takes only one column, I need to go through several different cells and columns, since the same value is in several cells as shown in the image

Comment: My mistake. I understand what you are saying. Can you try something like this:  int _count = dgLista.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.SelectMany(row=>row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>))
.Where(x => x.Value.ToString() == "01").ToList().Count();

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I'm poor on this subject.
I get an error, =the arguments of method type "Enumerable.SelectMany" "cannot be inferred based on usage, try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: Sorry, typo: .SelectMany(row => row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>())

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper I managed to make it work correctly, the ERROR "I was loading the code before the DataGridView", as soon as I realized I fixed it and it worked, Thank you very much for your help, a big hug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to solve this problem. The simplest is to traverse the grid's `.Rows` and their `.Cells` to count the occurrence of the given value.

```cs
private void calculaTotalGrid()
{
    int valToCount = 10;
    int count = 0;

    foreach (var row in dgLista.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
        foreach (var cell in row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>())
            count += int.TryParse(cell.Value?.ToString(), out int val) &&
                val == valToCount ? 1 : 0;

    txtNum.Text = count.ToString();
}
```

Or, execute a `Linq` query to [flatten](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany%2560%25602)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0) the grid's cells into a sequence and count the cells of the given value.

```cs
var count = dgLista.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .SelectMany(r => r.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
    .Where(c => int.TryParse(c.Value?.ToString(), out int val) && val == valToCount))
    .Count();
```

Or, use the [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate%2560%25601)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-aggregate-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-1-system-func((-1-0-1)))) method instead.

```cs
var count = dgLista.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Aggregate(0, (total, row) => total += row.Cells
    .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
    .Count(c => c.Value != null && int.Parse(c.Value.ToString()) == valToCount));
```

---

According to your last revision and comments, you need to get the count of the distinct values starting from column 1 (`concurso` column is not included). If so, I suggest a one-liner `Linq` query to group the cells by their unique values and create a `Dictopnary<int, int>` instead of the `ResultadoNumeros` class. This way, you don't need to repeat one of the previous solutions for each value.

```cs
private Dictionary<int, int> ResultadoNumeros;

private void calculaTotalGrid()
{
    int outVal = 0;
    ResultadoNumeros = dgLista.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .SelectMany(r => r.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
        .Where(c => c.ColumnIndex > 0 && int.TryParse(c.Value?.ToString(), out outVal)))
        .GroupBy(c => int.Parse(c.Value.ToString()))
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

    foreach (var kvp in ResultadoNumeros)
        Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key} -> {kvp.Value}");
}
```

To get the count of value `15` for example:

```cs
int count15 = ResultadoNumeros[15];
```

Or call the `TryGetValue` method to avoid throwing the `KeyNotFoundException` if the dictionary does not contain a given `Key`.

```cs
int outVal = 0;

if (ResultadoNumeros.TryGetValue(15, out outVal))
    Console.WriteLine(outVal);
```

See also:

- [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keys?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%25602.Keys)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0#definition) property.
- [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ContainsKey(TKey)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%25602.ContainsKey)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0) method.
- [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%25602.Values)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0) property.
- [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ContainsValue(TValue)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containsvalue?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%25602.ContainsValue)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0) method.

Comment: dr.null I am very grateful for your help, I did not find the word "int Val && Val" that is generating an error,(Syntax Error "," expected, the name Val exists in the current context) I am sorry, I have read so much about that's why I'm blind.

Comment: @EdilsonLemos No problem. Which solution have you picked? Pay attention to the braces `(` and `)`. Edit your question and add the code that you have implemented to take a look at it.

Comment: @EdilsonLemos You're welcome but wait a sec. Based on your last edit, is the grid.DataSource bound to the `DataTable` returned from the `ObterNumeros` method? And are you trying to extract all the counts from the grid to create a `ResultadoNumeros` instance that have a property for each count? `_01`, `_02`, ... `_15`. If so, we could find something better and faster using the `DataTable` functionalities instead.

Comment: @EdilsonLemos Sure, I'll suggest some more examples. Give some time though. Meanwhile, you can take a nap.

Comment: @EdilsonLemos See whether the last solution is acceptable. Good luck.

Comment: @EdilsonLemos Changed to meet your old c# language version. Upgrade!

Comment: I'm happy with your help, but I don't want to abuse your kindness, take one more doubt if possible, how could I get this result ( int count1 = ResultNumbers[01];) that is in the Grid of form2 and show it on the label in form1 "Main" ?

Comment: @EdilsonLemos Create `internal` method with `int` parameter that can be called from other contexts and returns the count of the passed number. Ex. in form2 `internal int GetCountOf(int number) { return ResultNumbers[number]; }`. Call it from the other form like: `someLabel.Text = form2.GetCountOf(1).ToString();`.

Comment: I would need to create a variable " int ResultNumber" to be recognized by (return ResultNumbers[number]; )? since the ResultNumber does not exist.

Comment: @EdilsonLemos No, you have already created `ResultadoNumeros` dictionary and the suggested method requests the `count` or the value of the passed `key` in the `number` param. Perhaps I don't understand what you are asking since it's a different problem. Maybe asking a new question for the new problem is a good idea.